# Function for performing Chi-squred and anova tests exhaustively on all categorical variables in python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, anova, chi-squared

I am working on a dataset which has both categorical and numerical variables. I want to find the correlations in the variables and if the their is huge correlation, I would like to drop one of the correlated features. I understand that the pandas `data.corr()` can only be used for numerical variables and categorical variables with only 2 values as 0 or 1. If I want to find the correlations among the categorical variables and a categorical variables, I learnt I will have to use chi-squared test and ANOVA test respectively. I have found that pandas and scipy have APIs which calculate the relation between a categorical feature and the label to be predicted. But this gives a idea about only about the categorical variable and the label to be predicted.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

X = churn_df.drop('Exited',axis=1)
y = churn_df['Exited'] 

chi_scores = chi2(X,y)
print(chi_scores)
```

Is there any function or API for chi-squared and anova tests which gives the exhaustive list of correlations for all the categorical variables, like pandas `data.corr()` does for all the numerical variables. Bases on the correlations in the categorical variables, I would like to drop them.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html https://www.pythonfordatascience.org/anova-python/

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-chi-square-test-in-python-4e9f5d10249d